# How to make a call to Amazon MWS Orders with PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-mws

I am having much trouble and frustration getting set up making API calls to the **orders** section of **Amazon MWS**.

When I use [Amazon MWS Scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html) I am able to get a successful response, but when I make the call on my own I get the error:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.
Consult the service documentation for details.
```

I could be wrong, but I think there must be something wrong with the way I am actually making the call, because even when I use the exact call that's created through the Scratchpad, I am still receiving the same error.

Nonetheless, here is the code I am trying to build up the request:

```
<?php

$secretKey = '<MY SECRET KEY>';

$parameters = array();

// required parameters
$parameters['Action']               = 'ListOrders';
$parameters['AWSAccessKeyId']       = '<MY ACCESS KEY>';
$parameters['MWSAuthToken']         = '<MY AUTH TOKEN>';
$parameters['SellerId']             = '<MY SELLER ID>';
$parameters['SignatureMethod']      = 'HmacSHA256';
$parameters['SignatureVersion']     = '2';
$parameters['Timestamp']            = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
$parameters['Version']              = '2013-09-01';

// optional parameters
$parameters['MarketplaceId.Id.1']   = '<MARKETPLACE ID>';
$parameters['CreatedAfter']         = '2015-10-04T04%3A00%3A00Z';

/**
 * Calculate String to Sign
 * 
 * @param array $parameters request parameters
 * @return String to Sign
 */
function _calculateStringToSign(array $parameters) {
    $data = "POST\n";
    $data .= "mws.amazonservices.com\n";
    $data .= "/Orders/2013-09-01\n";        
    $data .= _getParametersAsString($parameters);
    return $data;
}


/**
 * Convert paremeters to Url encoded query string
 */
function _getParametersAsString(array $parameters)
{
    uksort($parameters, 'strcmp');
    $queryParameters = array();
    foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
        $queryParameters[] = $key . '=' . _urlencode($value);
    }
    return implode('&', $queryParameters);
}

function _urlencode($value) {
    return str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($value));
}

/**
 * Computes RFC 2104-compliant HMAC signature.
 */
function _sign($stringToSign, $secretKey)
{
    $hash = 'sha256';

    return urlencode(base64_encode(
        hash_hmac($hash, $stringToSign, $secretKey, true)
    ));
}

/**
 * Builds up the request.
 */
function buildRequest(array $parameters, $secretKey) {
    $endpoint = 'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01';

    $signature = _sign(_calculateStringToSign($parameters), $secretKey);
    $parameters['Signature'] = $signature;

    uksort($parameters, 'strcmp');
    return $endpoint . '?' . _getParametersAsString($parameters);
}
```

And here is the code that actually makes the call:

```
$request = buildRequest($parameters, $secretKey);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36');
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($page);
```

I need help identifying where this script is going wrong and why I am not able to get a successful response.

Comment: Did you solve your Issue? I think I'm facing the same problem(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874090/amazon-mws-listorders-from-scratchpad-to-request)

Comment: @A.. This was a long time ago I hardly remember. I think the answer here was helpful and I also had to change the order of the parameters. I can try and find the code i used a little later today if u haven't gotten it by then

Comment: later I'm going to change the orders of the parameters... but if you could show me your code I would be grateful!

Comment: @A.. i just copied the code i was using to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tam5/01f90f1a55a3d466efa4b504a1984224). I don't have time to test it or really go through it, it was part of a Laravel project. Not sure how good the code is or anything bc it was a while ago, but you should be able to use it to get a successful response. Ill check back later when i have more time to see if you've got it

Comment: thank you very much, this evening I'm going to try it out!! If it works please reply to my question and I'll give you right answer.

Comment: I tried your code! It works! If you want you can answer my question. THank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```
$secretKey = 'ENTERVALUE';

$parameters = array();

// required parameters
$parameters['AWSAccessKeyId']       = 'ENTERVALUE';
$parameters['Action']               = 'GetOrder';
$parameters['AmazonOrderId.Id.1']   = 'ENTERVALUE';
$parameters['SellerId']             = 'ENTERVALUE';
$parameters['SignatureMethod']      = 'HmacSHA256';
$parameters['SignatureVersion']     = '2';
$parameters['Timestamp']            = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
$parameters['Version']              = '2013-09-01';




/**
 * Calculate String to Sign
 * 
 * @param array $parameters request parameters
 * @return String to Sign
 */
function _calculateStringToSign(array $parameters) {
    $data = "POST\n";
    $data .= "mws.amazonservices.com\n";
    $data .= "/Orders/2013-09-01\n";        
    $data .= _getParametersAsString($parameters);
    return $data;
}


/**
 * Convert paremeters to Url encoded query string
 */
function _getParametersAsString(array $parameters)
{
    uksort($parameters, 'strcmp');
    $queryParameters = array();
    foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
        $queryParameters[] = $key . '=' . _urlencode($value);
    }
    return implode('&', $queryParameters);
}

function _urlencode($value) {
    return str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($value));
}

/**
 * Computes RFC 2104-compliant HMAC signature.
 */
function _sign($stringToSign, $secretKey)
{
    //HmacSHA1
    $hash = 'sha256';

    return base64_encode(
        hash_hmac($hash, $stringToSign, $secretKey, true)
    );
}

/**
 * Builds up the request.
 */
function buildRequest(array $parameters, $secretKey) {
    //$endpoint = 'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01';

    $signature = _sign(_calculateStringToSign($parameters), $secretKey);
    $parameters['Signature'] = $signature;

    uksort($parameters, 'strcmp');
    return _getParametersAsString($parameters);
}

$request = buildRequest($parameters, $secretKey);



$allHeaders = array();
    $allHeaders['Content-Type'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"; // We need to make sure to set utf-8 encoding here
    $allHeaders['Expect'] = null; // Don't expect 100 Continue
    $allHeadersStr = array();
    foreach($allHeaders as $name => $val) {
        $str = $name . ": ";
        if(isset($val)) {
            $str = $str . $val;
        }
        $allHeadersStr[] = $str;
    }


//complete string
//echo $endpoint . '?' .$request;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $allHeadersStr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $response );
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to sound stupid, but with the code you have currently, you're making a `GET` request yet you sign it as `POST`.

Change the first line of the signature from `POST` to `GET` and the signature should go through perfectly fine.

Comment: @tam - Okay, so if it's a POST request, add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`. It'll send the request with an empty postbody. However, I'm dubious as to whether that is the case, as v2 signatures only work on GET requests. Furthermore, the comparison you're using to sort parameters is wrong - it's not a str comparison but a byte comparison. Join the parameters up then `sort` them.

Comment: you were mostly right. I did in fact need to make a `GET` request instead of a `POST` so thanks for that and +1. There was another issue though which was that for some reason the `Signature` had to be put at the end of the query, doing this made it work for me. No idea why and especially no idea why that is not mentioned anywhere, but got it to work. I'll update my question with the code that finally worked.