# Amazon MWS ListOrders from Scratchpad to request

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm trying to get the list of orders through the MWS Scratchpad.
In the scratchpad everything works fine.

The HTTP POST is

```
POST /Orders/2013-09-01?AWSAccessKeyId=$CHIAVE_ACCESSO
&Action=ListOrders
&SellerId=$SELLER_ID
&SignatureVersion=2
&Timestamp=2016-11-29T18%3A58%3A52Z
&Version=2013-09-01
&Signature=$SIGNATURE
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&CreatedAfter=2016-10-31T23%3A00%3A00Z
&MarketplaceId.Id.1=APJ6JRA9NG5V4 HTTP/1.1
Host: mws.amazonservices.it
x-amazon-user-agent: AmazonJavascriptScratchpad/1.0 (Language=Javascript)
Content-Type: text/xml
```

and the string to Sign (in the second box) is

```
POST
mws.amazonservices.it
/Orders/2013-09-01
AWSAccessKeyId=$CHIAVE_ACCESSO&Action=ListOrders&CreatedAfter=2016-10-31T23%3A00%3A00Z&MarketplaceId.Id.1=APJ6JRA9NG5V4&SellerId=$SELLER_ID&Signat    ureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2016-11-29T18%3A58%3A52Z&Version=2013-09-01
```

The results that shows the scratchpad are right.

What I would like to do is to make the request via PHP and elaborate the result.

But If I fist try to put the request on my browser like

https://mws.amazonservices.it/Orders/2013-09-01?AWSAccessKeyId=$CHIAVE_ACCESSO&Action=ListOrders&MarketplaceId=APJ6JRA9NG5V4&SellerId=$SELLER_ID&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2016-11-29T19%3A13%3A01.000Z&Version=2013-09-01&Signature=Q9Xnr9JhtkzeLUAsCFKPln8SS34FkCQRmELE2WiIhPo%3D&CreatedAfter=2016-10-31T23%3A00%3A00Z

the error is 
[image: error]

The Method I used to create the signature was find on stackoverflow and is the following:

```
$sign  = 'GET' . "\n";
$sign .= 'mws.amazonservices.it' . "\n";
$sign .= '/Orders/2013-09-01' . "\n";
$sign .= $arr;

$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $sign, $CHIAVE_SEGRETA, true);
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));
```

What I'm doing Wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the parameters matters.

Here is some sample code that should give you a good place to start. You'll just need to modify it slightly to fit your system.

```
class AmazonMWS
{
    private $secretKey = '';

    private $parameters = array();

    /**
     * Constructor for the AmazonMWS class.
     * Initializes constants.
     */
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->secretKey = Constant::get('SECRET_KEY');

        $this->parameters['AWSAccessKeyId']     = Constant::get('AWSAccessKeyId');
        $this->parameters['MarketplaceId.Id.1'] = Constant::get('MarketplaceId.Id.1');
        $this->parameters['SellerId']           = Constant::get('SellerId');
        $this->parameters['SignatureMethod']    = Constant::get('SignatureMethod');
        $this->parameters['SignatureVersion']   = Constant::get('SignatureVersion');
    }

    public function setListOrders()
    {
        $this->parameters['Action'] = 'ListOrders';
        $this->parameters['Version'] = '2013-09-01';
        $this->parameters['Timestamp'] = $this->getTimestamp();

        // this part should change and depend on the method/parameter.. for now just for testing

        $this->parameters['CreatedAfter'] = '2015-11-01';
    }

    public function listOrders()
    {
        $request = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01?";
        $request .= $this->getParameterString($this->parameters) . "&Signature=" . $this->calculateSignature($this->calculateStringToSign($this->parameters));

        echo $request;

        return Curl::fetchSSL($request);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates String to sign.
     * 
     * @param array $parameters request parameters
     * @return String to sign
     */
    protected function calculateStringToSign(array $parameters)
    {
        $stringToSign  = 'GET' . "\n";
        $stringToSign .= 'mws.amazonservices.com' . "\n";
        $stringToSign .= '/Orders/2013-09-01' . "\n";
        $stringToSign .= $this->getParameterString($parameters);

        return $stringToSign;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the query parameters as a String sorted in natural-byte order.
     * 
     * @param array $parameters request parameters
     * @return String of parameters
     */
    protected function getParameterString(array $parameters)
    {
        $url = array();
        foreach ($parameters as $key => $val) {
            $key = $this->urlEncode($key);
            $val = $this->urlEncode($val);
            $url[] = "{$key}={$val}";
        }
        sort($url);

        $parameterString = implode('&', $url);

        return $parameterString;
    }

    /**
     * Computes RFC 2104-compliant HMAC signature.
     *
     * @param String to sign
     */
    protected function calculateSignature($stringToSign)
    {
        $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $stringToSign, $this->secretKey, true);
        return urlencode(base64_encode($signature));
    }

    /**
     * URL encodes a string.
     */
    protected function urlEncode($string)
    {
        return str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($string));
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current date as ISO 8601 timestamp
     */
    protected function getTimestamp()
    {
        return gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error : " Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Curl' not found" Do you remember what Class did you use? thanks

Comment: @robot11 that is pseudocode for the sake of the answer. you will need to decide for yourself how to make the request. using curl is fine or check out guzzle if you want a package

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [PHP client library](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/orders/orders/v20130901/php.html/154-8806927-8947634) for the Orders API?  I use the C# version, but I would assume the PHP library is similar.  Most of the work is done for you.

Comment: I saw it but it seems a little bit out of date because last update is in date 2013...

Comment: Actually it was last updated near the end of 2015, just look at the code inside.  The client library is based on the latest version of the API, which is where 2013 comes from.